# assign roles and rights to ASP.NET MVC 5 ApplicationUser with jqGrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, jqgrid, asp.net-identity

I want to integrate jqGrid into a new MVC 5 view (standard VS 2013 ASP.NET MVC 5 project template, not the empty one..) in order to be able to configure the user's role and some additional rights for the users (boolean properties of ApplicationUser, e.g. IsUserDisabled, IsUserAllowedToUseChat.. etc.). The role will be assigned in a jqGrid inline-edit mode to a user with a dropdown for selecting the user's role(user can only have one role at a time). The additional "rights" like IsUserDisabled, IsUserAllowedToUseChat i would like to be able to configure with checkboxes for each boolean property of ApplicationUser.

I am a beginner in ASP.NET MVC (and Entity Framework) and i have some questions:

1) Is my approach basically correct and do i need an extra controller for the jqGrid's CRUD operations or should i integrate everything in HomeController? (For now i'ts the only grid used in the project.)

2) Should the .js and .css files be referenced in my actual (Grid)View.cshtml or in the _Layout.cshtml or elsewhere?

3) Do you know a good example/tutorial for "painless" integration of Trirand jqGrid into ASP.NET MVC 5?

When i try the jqGrid integration on my own, i get a runtime javascript error saying that jQuery is undefined and stuff.. So i would prefer a good tutorial for a clean and proper integration of jqGrid into ASP.NET MVC 5 preferably using NuGet.

Comment: I would highly recommend installing jqGrid as a [NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.jqGrid/). It will install all of the required dependencies for you (jQuery, etc.).

Comment: Thanks. I installed this one: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Trirand.jqGrid/  and get the error. Is it because of the different package? The one i am using has a greater version (4.6.0 vs 4.4.4). Right now i am not at home, so i can't try out..

Comment: Can someone please confirm that this (my problem above) can work with jqGrid 4.6.0? Or do i have to use jqGrid 4.4.4 instead?

Comment: jqGrid is just an extension of jQuery and jQuery UI. It integrates into any web application technology you'd like. Your questions are very broad and have more to do with MVC best practices than with jqGrid itself. Quick answers: 1) You don't *need* an extra controller, but may want one if you're going to have a lot of actions specific to the grid. 2) Use `_Layout.cshtml` if you have grids all over. Otherwise, use the `@section head { }` area of your view to include the CSS and JS. 3) The Trirand site has countless [demos](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html).

Comment: Also, here's a great tutorial on integrating into MVC4. Should work well with MVC5 too: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/594150/MVC-Basic-Site-Step-jqGrid-In

Comment: @Cory: Thank you. 1) The same i was thinking, because it's the only grid which doesn't have that much functions i will leave it in HomeController  2) Thanks again, i didn't know that there even is '@secion head' for specifiying where to render something in MVC view! :-)  3) I know the Trirand-demos and i understand most of them (jsfiddle helps me a lot here), but problem is that i am total newbie when it comes to MVC/Razor and i can't get the jqGrid even running. With your informations i will give it a next try! :-)